# Computer with static ip unable to print to Ethernet printer with dynamic ip

Tags: networking, router, printer, static-ip

I have a static ip address on my computer that I bought from ATT and am unable to print to my canon ethernet network printer that gets a dynamic ip address from the u-verse router. All my other computers that get dynamic ip addresses can print fine except for this one computer with the static ip address. I am unable to ping this printer from the computer with the static ip.

How can I print from my computer with the static ip to my ethernet printer? Ideally I would like all my computers to print to the printer.

Comment: My first thought is you probably should not be putting your printer directly on the internet. I'd buy a router, put the public static IP on the router, and use private addresses inside the router. any services you run on the PC can be port forwarded through the router, so you keep all the benifets of having a static public IP, but lose all the negatives like lack of hardware firewall, inadvertent service exposure, discoverability of personal devices from the internet,  etc.

Comment: What are the IP addresses of the PC and the printer?

Comment: computer ip is something like 107.155.122.1 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0 but the printer ip is 192.168.1.66 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: well, the problem there is that your printer is part of a private network (RFC1918 defines 192.168.0/16 as a private network) and your PC is public. that means that your printer is recieving its IP address from some piece of equipment, similar to a home router or even a simple cable-modem. that piece of equipment will have a public IP assigned to it, so in order to connect, you will need to determine and connect via this public IP (or reconfigure your network as I outlined in my prior comment). you may need to modify the devices settings to pass traffic from the WAN.

Answer (score 0):

The PC is left with the address it had before it was sold to you. That address bears no relation to your current network, and so your router will not connect the PC and printer.

To fix it, you need change the PC to use DHCP and get a dynamic address from your router, like the printer is doing.

This can be done from Network Properties, but the details vary a bit depending on which version of Windows you have. See http://windows7themes.net/en-us/how-to-enable-dhcp-in-windows/#network_properties

Comment: no, I use the static ip and this computer's static ip is correct. the rest of my computers use dynamic ips. the static ip computer is having trouble printing to the network printer which gets a dynamic ip.

Comment: Your static IP is on a completely different network from the printer. You'll find the other PCs have IP addresses on the 192.168.1.x subnet, like the printer. Your "new" PC needs to be on the same subnet, and the easiest way to do that is by enabling DHCP .

Comment: Maybe I need a second ethernet card then?

Comment: No, you only need 1 Ethernet card. DHCP will give it an address in the 192.168.1.x range, and you will be able to talk to the printer. Just try my suggestion. Make a note of the current settings before you make the change to DHCP. If it doesn't work, you can then set the PC back to its current settings.

Comment: Thanks but i need to keep the static ip

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from AT&T. They said their router is unable to do a static route to let a computer with a static IP communicate with a device that gets a dynamic IP on the same network.

The suggested fix was to buy separate router, assign the new router the static ip, and then let the new router control the network and all devices would be able to communicate.